# Separar hora de un string - Angular

Tags: angular, ionic

Lo que pasa es que tengo una API que me está retornando **2021-11-23 13:00:00** y no encuentro la forma de separar para quedar solo con la hora, osea **13:00:00**

Comment: y que has intentado???

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Código o Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible, Me parece que a tu POST contiene código no formateado, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: // ts  today: number = Date.now();  //html <p>Or if you prefer, {{today | date:'mediumTime'}}</p>......>  en la pagina de angular.io busca DatePipe

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una nueva fecha:

```javascript
nuevaFecha = new Date("2021-11-23 13:00:00")
```

Y llamar al [pipe Date](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

```html
{{nuevaFecha: date:'HH:MM:ss'}}
```

Es posible utilizarlo en el componente. Para esto lo importas en tu app.module (O el modulo que quiereas utilizar)

```javascript
//MAS CODIGO....
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [  DatePipe ] //<== Aquí se agrega
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Y lo inyectas como un servicio en tu componente:

```javascript
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  nuevaFecha = new Date('2021-11-23 13:00:00');

  miObjeto = {
    miFechaCortada: this.datePipe.transform(this.nuevaFecha, 'HH:MM:ss'),
  };
}
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-od7wis?file=src/app/app.component.ts)